# Quicker way to join multiple lists passed as args to a Python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, concatenation

So I have a function which takes a variable number of lists as an argument, then combines those lists into one single list:

```
def comb_lists(*lists):
    sublist = []
    for l in lists:
        sublist.extend(l)
    print(sublist)
    
>>> comb_lists([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And it works. But I was just wondering if there was a simpler solution? I tried a list comprehension using list unpacking, but that returned a SyntaxError:

```
def comb_lists(*lists):
    sublist = [*l for l in lists]
    
>>> comb_lists([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])
SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension
```

Is there any neater or quicker way to do this?

**EDIT:** itertools looks really useful for this sort of thing. I'd be interested to know if there's any way of doing it that doesn't rely on imports though.

Comment: Try `list(itertools.chain(*lists))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the simplest solution

```
result = sum(lists, [])
```

Comment: That's very elegant and works perfectly! Why does it work, though? Why doesn't the sum function just add up the contents of the lists?

Comment: @Lou if the second param is given, then the sum function adds the value of iterable to the second param one by one. "lists" is actually list of list, that's why it didn't add up the content. ref: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sum

Answer (score 1):

There's *built-in* function [`chain.form_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) in [*itertools*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module to do this:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> my_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

>>> list(chain.from_iterable(my_list))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you do not want to import any module, you can write *nested list comprehension* to achieve this as:

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

>>> [e for l in my_list for e in l]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd be interested to know if there's any other solutions that don't use imports, but this is a useful answer nevertheless

Comment: @Lou Updated with *list comprehension* based solution